# Not able to redirect to "https://www.google.com/india" using anchor tag

Tags: html

```
<a href="https://www.google.com/india"> about india </a>
```

404. That’s an error.
     The requested URL /india was not found on this server. That’s all we know.

Comment: Because the URL does not exist. Try running on browser.

Comment: It doesn't exist. I just tried it on my browser. Find the valid URL you need. Are you trying to link a search of the term "india"? It would be "https://www.google.com/search?q=india"

Comment: If you want to access google India, try https://www.google.co.in/

Answer (score 1):

You are getting 404 error because the URL you are using doesn't exist. Try using any other URL.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 404 indicates that the resource you are looking for is not found.

Change the URL to

https://www.google.in

```html
<a href="https://www.google.in" target="_blank"> about india </a>
```

Comment: Still not working